# Inserting a file into mysql DB via CMD

Tags: mysql, cmd

My question is simple I thought, but I did not get it right yet . .

I am having a simple db in mysql server 5.1 -

Which includes a file to be saved in as db format "blob"

How do I save a file in the database ? assuming it is 2 fields, one id - int one blob for the file !?! Is blob right ? Want to save microsoft word and pdf documents !!

I want to insert it via CMD, and struggel, when putting a file path in, it saves the path, but no file !!

E.G. >

```
INSERT INTO cvtable VALUES("1","???file path???");
```

Thank you guys for any hints here !!

Comment: Whey you say *CMD*, do you mean a Windows *.cmd batch script?

Comment: just via command line interface, i'd like to insert the file into mysql database. As i said, i can do so with normal fields, but nor sure about how to get a file inserted / saved in the DB . .!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert into cv (id,content) values ("1",LOAD_FILE('cv.doc'));

thats what i was looking for !!

finally !!!

Comment: @OscarJara , use this `INSERT INTO my_table (stamp, docFile) VALUES (NOW(), LOAD_FILE('/tmp/my_file.odt'));`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have a look at the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement.

Comment: when loading data via a file, do i then just put the file path into the txt file ?? And is blob the right format to save a doc / pdf ??

Comment: I do find alot of php, java , perl scripts etc. To upload files. But for now I just manually want to insert and store files in the database !

Comment: @Alexander - No, this command loads the actual file into the database. Read the link I gave.

Comment: "The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed. The file name must be given as a literal string. "  -> it reads the lines of a txt file !!

Comment: @Alexander - What data are you loading? You did not specify. Also, please stop with the exclamation marks (!'s) if you don't mind.

Comment: it is specified, i want to load a word doc or pdf document into the database (safe it in the DB)- by looking at the table, i am specifying, it is supposed to hold a CV e.g.

Comment: @Alex - My mistake, I did not see that you specified that. To be honest, this would be far easier using a script to do the conversion into binary. Is this not available to you?

Comment: no not at the moment. I am sure there is a way of doing this via CMD, I can download several scripts in php, java etc, to do this for me. But I want to upload them VIA CMD - and have no clue how . . I do actually feel a little stupid not being able to figure it out to be honest.

Comment: @Alex - Don't feel stupid, I can't seem to find it either. It's not like it's obvious ;)